# Find a subdistribution

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $\alpha$ be a composition of $n$ into nonzero parts and let $\mathcal L$ be a set of permutations of a finite multiset having $n$ elements, such that each element of $\mathcal L$ is constant on each part of $\alpha$.

For example, for $n=8$ we could have $\alpha=(3, 2, 1, 1, 1)$ and $\mathcal L = \{ A A A | B B | A | B | C | , B B B | A A | C | A | A \}$.

Is there a good algorithm to decide whether there is a non-trivial subset $S$ of the parts of $\alpha$ such that for all elements $w$ in $\mathcal L$, the multiset of corresponding elements in $w$ is the same?

In the example above, taking $S=\{1,2,4\}$ designates a non-trivial subdistribution, consisting of three $A$'s and three $B$'s.

More generally, can we efficiently find all subsets $S$ which are minimal with respect to inclusion?

As a further example, if all parts of $\alpha$ are equal to $1$ and $\mathcal L$ consists of the identity permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and another permutation $\pi$, then the subsets $S$ are precisely the indices of the elements in the cycles of $\pi$.  Thus, it admits a non-trivial subdistribution if and only if $\pi$ is not a cycle.

UPDATE: The special case where all parts of $\alpha$ are equal to $1$ would be equally interesting.

Comment: This problem is as hard as the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem): Let $x_1,x_2,...,x_m$ be a set of numbers from which a subset having sum $x$ is to be found. Then let $\mathcal{L}=\{x_1A|x_2A|...,x_mA|xB,x_1B|x_2B|...|x_mB|xA\}$, and any solution corresponds to an answer to the subset sum problem.

Comment: From a practical prespective, what are the typical size of $\mathcal{L}$, and its number of types of elements?

Comment: Wow, that was quick (bad) news. I'll have to think about your question a little. In any case, a further complication is, that the elements of $\mathcal L$ are produced on request only, by solving another hard MILP.

Comment: More precisely, the MILP can answer the question "is there an element of $\mathcal L$ such that part $i$ has value $v$" and some variations thereof.

Comment: Subset sum is easy when the input is unary, which is the case here. It can be solved with dynamic programming, see knapsack problem. I would guess that this problem can also be solved with dp.

Comment: No, it cannot be solved with dp (unless P=NP).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $a_{i,j,k}$ denote the number of times in permutation $i$ and part $j$ that letter $k$ appears. Let binary decision variable $x_j$ indicate whether part $j$ is selected.  Let nonnegative integer decision variable $y_k$ represent the number of times letter $k$ is selected in each permutation.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_j x_j$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_j a_{i,j,k} x_j &= y_k &&\text{for all $i$ and $k$}\tag1 \\
\sum_j x_j &\ge 1 \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ forces each permutation $i$ to have the same number of appearances of letter $k$ across all selected parts.
Constraint $(2)$ avoids the trivial zero solution.

For your sample data, an optimal solution is $x=(0,0,1,0,1)$ and $y=(1,0,1)$, which corresponds to $S=\{3,5\}$, with one $A$ and one $C$.

Comment: In general, integer linear programming is NP-complete, so this algorithm is not known to be better than brute force checking all possibilities.

Comment: In practice, ILP is much better than brute force.

Comment: No offense, but converting the problem to an ILP or a SAT instance is an undergrad homework exercise.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-complete because you can reduce a special version of [3DM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching) to it, when every vertex is 3-regular (see (SP2) in Garey and Johnson).
Suppose that we are given a 3-uniform hypergraph $(V,E)$ as an input of 3DM.
The vertices of the hypergraph $V$ will correspond to the permutations of $\mathcal L$, such that each permutation will consist of singleton A's and B's, for example, A|B|B|A|A.
We pick $n=|E|$, the number of edges of the hypergraph.
If a vertex is incident to an edge, then we put a B to the corresponding part, otherwise an A.
The 3-regularity condition implies that every part has exactly 3 B's.

Note that whenever we pick an edge, it will contain at least one vertex, so the union of the parts has to contain at least one B.
It cannot contain 3 B's, because then it would need to contain every part.
If it contains 2 B's, then its complement would contain exactly one B.
Finally, if it contains exactly 1 B, then it is a 3DM.
From here it is straightforward to see that this has a solution if and only if the 3DM had one.

Comment: Can we do significantly better if the composition $\alpha$ has only singleton parts?  If additionally $\mathcal L$ has only two elements, we can proceed very similarly to the case of permutations, but it is unclear to me how to generalize to larger $\mathcal L$.

Comment: I've updated my answer to prove this stronger version, I think it even became clearer than the original, and I hope it is still correct.

Comment: Thank you!  However, I have trouble understanding: I don't see why I should have the same number of A's in every permutation (corresponding to a vertex), in particular, if there is a special vertex incident to only one edge.

Comment: If you have the same number of B's (which is one), and in total you have the same number of letters, then you must also have the same number of A's (which is the number of selected parts minus one).

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand.  The elements of $\mathcal L$ are supposed to be (some) permutations of a fixed finite multiset.  So, if $\mathcal L$ contains an element which has just one occurrence of $B$, all other letters being $A$'s, this is the case for all elements of $\mathcal L$.  But then the problem is very easy to solve.

Comment: You're right! I've updated my answer.

Comment: That's great that you were able to fix the problems, although it is in fact quite a problem for me that this problem is hard.  Any ideas for a heuristic?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know much about that, my job, similar to John Oliver's, is limited to making people sad, by showing that their problems are hard. You could try the IP solver approach of RobPratt, or a SAT solver.